# Problems with UPLOAD to FTP -> ftp_put(): Quotas off

Tags: php, xampp

I'm developing a system that upload files from a local folder to my ftp, but sometimes i'm getting this

**error**

> ftp_put(): Quotas off...

I Notice this is some configuration in my local server, i tested in other local server and works. But i need this script works in XAMPP.

This is the method i'm using to upload from local to ftp

```
ftp_put($conn_id, $fileOnline, $fileLocal, FTP_BINARY)
```